# Correspondence Theorem in rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to do an exercise from the book: T. W. Hungerford, Algebra. Springer.

It is the Theorem 2.13 of chapter III:

*Theorem*: If $I$ is an ideal in a ring $R$, then there is a one-to-one correspondence between the set of all ideals of $R$ which contain $I$ and the set of all ideals of $R/I$, given by $J \rightarrow J/I$. Hence every ideal in $R/I$ is of the form $J/I$, where $J$ is an ideal of $R$ which contains $I$.

The author indicates to see Theorem I.5.11, Corollary I.5.12 and Exercice 13.

These indicated results are the analogues for group theory, but in the Theorem I.5.11 is supposed that there exist a epimorphism $f: G \rightarrow H$, where $G$ and $H$ are groups. In the case of rings, this is not supposed.

I'm having a hard time adapting because of that. I thought about proving by doing the calculations with sets, but as the author indicated these results, I believe there is some way to do it using homomorphisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I think you do have a surjective group homomorphism as the one you need: take $G:=R$, $H:=R/I$ and $f\colon G\to H$ the canonical projection. Then, the Correspondence Theorem for Abelian groups tells you that there is a bijections between $\mathcal L(H):=\{\text{subgroups of $H$}\}$ and $\mathcal L_{\ker(f)}(G):=\{\text{subgroups of $G$ containing $\ker(f)$}\}$. Call this bijection:
$$
\Phi\colon \mathcal L_{\ker(f)}(G)\to \mathcal L_{}(H)\qquad K\mapsto f(K).
$$

To conclude, it is enough to show that, given $K\in \mathcal L_{\ker(f)}(G)$ we have that $K$ is an ideal if, and only if $\Phi(K)$ is an ideal. But this is easy to see:

-- suppose that $K$ is an ideal of $R$ and that $\ker(f)\leq K$, then $f(K)$ is an ideal of $R/I$. In fact, given $k\in K$ and $r+I\in R/I$, we have that $r+I\cdot f(k)=f(r)\cdot f(k)=f(r\cdot k)\in f(K)$ (and similarly on the other side);

-- on the other hand, suppose that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $\ker(f)$ and $f(K)$ is an ideal of $R/I$. By the correspondence theorem, $K=f^{-1}f(K)$. Given $k\in K$ and $r\in R$, then $f(k\cdot r)=f(k)\cdot (r+I)\in f(K)$ as $f(K)$ is an ideal. Hence, $k\cdot r\in f^{-1}f(K)=K$, as desired. (One proceeds similarly on the other side).